# MobileFirst 7.1 - Bean creation error when manually cleaning bin directory

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

When I do clean build from Eclipse I have observed that it does not clean the war file. So to makes sure I have correct war file with updated changes I manually clean the war file by deleting it. After doing this if I redeploy the App I start seeing issue with Bean creation. Please have a look at the server logs.

```
     Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 10777
Launching worklight (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.5/wlp-1.0.8.cl50520150305-2202) on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.7.0_79-b15 (en_US)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server worklight has been launched.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications. 
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path javax.annotation-api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jsr181-api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxws-api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path javax.xml.soap-api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path FastInfoset.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path xml-apis.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/analytics-service.war!/WEB-INF/lib/serializer-2.7.2.jar or its parent.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:10080/_MobileBrowserSimulator/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:10080/IBMJMXConnectorREST/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application _MobileBrowserSimulator started in 0.421 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:10080/analytics/
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path xercesImpl.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/analytics-service.war!/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path xml-apis.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/analytics-service.war!/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path serializer.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/analytics-service.war!/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path hk2-core.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/ha-api.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path class-model.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/ha-api.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path config.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/ha-api.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path auto-depends.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/ha-api.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path javax.inject.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/ha-api.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path asm-all-repackaged.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/ha-api.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path hk2-api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/ha-api.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path osgi-resource-locator.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/ha-api.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path tiger-types.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/ha-api.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path bean-validator.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/ha-api.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jtype.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/ha-api.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxb-core-2.2.10-b140802.1033.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-core.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxb-api-2.2.12-b140109.1041.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-core.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path istack-commons-runtime-2.19.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-core.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path txw2-2.2.10-b140802.1033.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-core.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path mimepull.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path saaj-impl.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxb-api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/worklight-management-ui.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path activation.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/worklight-management-ui.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jsr173_1.0_api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/worklight-management-ui.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxb1-impl.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/worklight-management-ui.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path stax2-api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path woodstox-core-asl.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path javax.annotation-api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jsr181-api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxws-api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path javax.xml.soap-api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path FastInfoset.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path hk2-core.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/ha-api.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path class-model.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/ha-api.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path config.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/ha-api.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path auto-depends.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/ha-api.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path javax.inject.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/ha-api.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path asm-all-repackaged.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/ha-api.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path hk2-api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/ha-api.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path osgi-resource-locator.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/ha-api.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path tiger-types.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/ha-api.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path bean-validator.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/ha-api.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jtype.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/ha-api.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxb-core-2.2.10-b140802.1033.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-core.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxb-api-2.2.12-b140109.1041.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-core.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path istack-commons-runtime-2.19.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-core.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path txw2-2.2.10-b140802.1033.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-core.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path mimepull.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path saaj-impl.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path stax2-api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path woodstox-core-asl.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/DHSProject.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxb-api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/worklight-management-ui.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path activation.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/worklight-management-ui.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jsr173_1.0_api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/worklight-management-ui.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxb1-impl.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/worklight-management-ui.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxb-api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/worklight-management-service.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path activation.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/worklight-management-service.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jsr173_1.0_api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/worklight-management-service.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxb1-impl.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/worklight-management-service.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application AnalyticsUI started in 2.580 seconds.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxb-api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/worklight-management-service.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path activation.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/worklight-management-service.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jsr173_1.0_api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/worklight-management-service.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxb1-impl.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/worklight-management-service.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:10080/DHSProject/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:10080/worklightconsole/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application WorklightConsole started in 3.410 seconds.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path xml-apis.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/analytics-service.war!/WEB-INF/lib/serializer-2.7.2.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path xercesImpl.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/analytics-service.war!/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path xml-apis.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/analytics-service.war!/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path serializer.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/analytics-service.war!/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar or its parent.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:10080/analytics-service/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:10080/worklightadmin/
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.QueryParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.core.Context annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.CookieParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.PathParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.MatrixParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] Using empty value for configuration property 'wl.analytics.logs.packages'
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application DHSProject started in 5.599 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application WorklightServices started in 8.192 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application AnalyticsServices started in 8.437 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: [appSecurity-1.0, jdbc-4.0, ldapRegistry-3.0, ssl-1.0, localConnector-1.0, json-1.0, appSecurity-2.0, jsp-2.2, restConnector-1.0, servlet-3.0, jaxrs-1.1, jndi-1.0, distributedMap-1.0].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The server worklight is ready to run a smarter planet.
[WARNING ] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
Error creating bean with name 'taskManager' defined in URL [wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'worklightAuthenticationService' while setting bean property 'authenticationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'worklightAuthenticationService' defined in URL [wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'loginConfigurationServiceBean' while setting bean property 'loginConfigurationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginConfigurationServiceBean' defined in URL [wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Class 'gov.ga.dhs.css.mobile.auth.CustomLoginModule' defined in login module 'CustomLoginModule' in the authentication configuration file doesn't exist.
[ERROR   ] FWLST0003E: ========= Failed starting project /DHSProject [project DHSProject]
Error creating bean with name 'taskManager' defined in URL [wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'worklightAuthenticationService' while setting bean property 'authenticationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'worklightAuthenticationService' defined in URL [wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'loginConfigurationServiceBean' while setting bean property 'loginConfigurationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginConfigurationServiceBean' defined in URL [wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Class 'gov.ga.dhs.css.mobile.auth.CustomLoginModule' defined in login module 'CustomLoginModule' in the authentication configuration file doesn't exist.
[ERROR   ] Error creating bean with name 'taskManager' defined in URL [wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'worklightAuthenticationService' while setting bean property 'authenticationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'worklightAuthenticationService' defined in URL [wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'loginConfigurationServiceBean' while setting bean property 'loginConfigurationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginConfigurationServiceBean' defined in URL [wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Class 'gov.ga.dhs.css.mobile.auth.CustomLoginModule' defined in login module 'CustomLoginModule' in the authentication configuration file doesn't exist.
Error creating bean with name 'taskManager' defined in URL [wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'worklightAuthenticationService' while setting bean property 'authenticationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'worklightAuthenticationService' defined in URL [wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'loginConfigurationServiceBean' while setting bean property 'loginConfigurationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginConfigurationServiceBean' defined in URL [wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Class 'gov.ga.dhs.css.mobile.auth.CustomLoginModule' defined in login module 'CustomLoginModule' in the authentication configuration file doesn't exist.
[ERROR   ] DHSProject: worklight///hostname: 2016-02-26T14:45:29.027Z: Error creating bean with name 'taskManager' defined in URL [wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'worklightAuthenticationService' while setting bean property 'authenticationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'worklightAuthenticationService' defined in URL [wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'loginConfigurationServiceBean' while setting bean property 'loginConfigurationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginConfigurationServiceBean' defined in URL [wsjar:file:MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Class 'gov.ga.dhs.css.mobile.auth.CustomLoginModule' defined in login module 'CustomLoginModule' in the authentication configuration file doesn't exist.
[ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: An exception occurred: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Console initialization failed.Logged Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Class &#39;gov.ga.dhs.css.mobile.auth.CustomLoginModule&#39; defined in login module &#39;CustomLoginModule&#39; in the authentication configuration file doesn&#39;t exist.
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.verifyServletInitialized(AuthenticationFilter.java:586)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:141)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
    at [internal classes]
    at com.worklight.analytics.AnalyticsFilter.doFilter(AnalyticsFilter.java:124)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Console initialization failed.Logged Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Class 'gov.ga.dhs.css.mobile.auth.CustomLoginModule' defined in login module 'CustomLoginModule' in the authentication configuration file doesn't exist.
    ... 8 more

[ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: An exception occurred: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Console initialization failed.Logged Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Class &#39;gov.ga.dhs.css.mobile.auth.CustomLoginModule&#39; defined in login module &#39;CustomLoginModule&#39; in the authentication configuration file doesn&#39;t exist.
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.verifyServletInitialized(AuthenticationFilter.java:586)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:141)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
    at [internal classes]
    at com.worklight.analytics.AnalyticsFilter.doFilter(AnalyticsFilter.java:124)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Console initialization failed.Logged Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Class 'gov.ga.dhs.css.mobile.auth.CustomLoginModule' defined in login module 'CustomLoginModule' in the authentication configuration file doesn't exist.
    ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you attempting to clear the bin to begin with? This is a task that is handled by MobileFirst Studio for you. Upon any change made on the server folder of your project, the war is being recreated. Rest assured that it is the latest (unless you can prove otherwise).

Comment: I guess Manually deleting was not the right way. Anyways now how do I fix the issue? How can I make it work. I deleted the MobileFirstServerConfig folder and deleted the server from eclipse and restarted the eclipse but I still see this issue

Comment: This is to inform that the war does not get updated by the eclipse sometimes. Like in my scenario I had to change my Java version  from 8 to 7 since then I tried clean build couple of times and it does not work.

Comment: What is your MFP studio version?